# How to use regular expression with form_validation library

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, validation

i want to add regular expression in `$this->form_validation->set_rules()` but unable to find any correct solution for that.
as i want that my input field should only have 0 or 1 so how can i place inside `setrules()` 
like

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('binary', 'Binary', 'required|regexp_match[*//code..]');`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The expression should be like:

```
/^[01]{1}$/           OR                 /^[01]$/
```

Which corresponds to:

- Only 1 or 0
- Only one symbol allowed

So (updated delimiters):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('binary', 'Binary', 'required|regex_match[/^[01]{1}$/]')
```

Comment: thanks @jari for help , but i think expession should be like..... $this->form_validation->set_rules('binary', 'Binary', 'required|regex_match[^[01]{1}$^]')                                                         otherwise it shows error " preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found"